# APEX_MAIL.send - can not recive mails after changing the host

Tags: oracle-apex

We are using APEX_MAIL.send procedure to send the mails. IT was working fine till now. Recently we have changed its hostaddress and after that it has stopped sending the mails.

My database version is 11.2.0.3 and APEX version is APEX 4.2.6

Can you please let me know what could be the reason and how can i resolve that.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Oracle database has internal access control lists that limit which network resources can be accessed by PL/SQL packages like APEX_MAIL. It also relies on an initialization parameter to define the default SMTP host. If you changed your mail host, then it is very likely that one or both of these needs to be updated.

See here for details about setting up ACLs in Oracle 11g: https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/fine-grained-access-to-network-services-11gr1

And see here for details about the SMTP_OUT_SERVER parameter: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17110/initparams239.htm